# Getting a picture from url(server) as client with c

Tags: c, url

using send and recv functions to get the buffer from server(url). I can connect to the server  with

```
sprintf (buffer, "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:%s\r\n\r\n", ip, host);
```

When i use send and recv functions, i can succesfully get the buffer as text with

```
printf("\n%s", buffer);
```

But i cant get the buffer as a picture(when there isnt a text, when there is a jpg in the url). How can i get the picture from the url.

Comment: When the image is delivered, it will be in its binary form. You will need to know its mime type to convert the bytes to an image of the correct type.